# Which Arab countries grant immigration to non-Arabs?

Tags: policy, immigration

I would like to know which Arab countries in the Middle East and the GCC (Gulf Cooperation Council) grant immigration (residency and/or political rights) to non-Arabs.

What are the policies and terms and conditions? And if there is no immigration at all then what is the political reasoning behind it?

The Arab League, a regional organization of countries intended to encompass the Arab world, defines an Arab as:

> An Arab is a person whose language is Arabic, who lives in an
>   Arabic-speaking country, and who is in sympathy with the aspirations
>   of the Arabic-speaking people.

Then there must be certain room for people who are aspiring to settle down in Arab countries!

<sup>**Note**: I am seeking credible and precise information on this subject</sup>

Comment: just to clarify, does the question include or exclude migrant workers (who don't really have residency and political rights as far as I know), who are common in UAE/Saudi Arabia?

Comment: Also, (1) does the question include or exclude non-Arab Muslims (e.g. Iranians, Pakistanis, Indonesians, or Uzbeks) as immigrants? (2) does it include or exclude non-Muslims who are ethnically Arab (e.g. Christians from Lebanon)?

Comment: @DVK The question includes everyone and anyone!

Comment: UAE! There are many Iranians, Europeans, Asians and Americans who have their second passport from UAE and live there for business, as political or social refugees, the matter of marriage and as workers.

Comment: @PersianCat it takes 30 years to become a UAE citizeb through naturalization alone. I don't think that counts...

Comment: Which Arab countries grant citizenship to Arabs? Do any of them have formal policies preferring Arabs?

Answer (score 2):

**Morocco**

Morocco has allowed many Spanish and French people to immigrate, mostly elderly retired people, allowing them to live at much lower cost than living in their countries would.

According to their 2014 census data available on [their government's website](http://www.data.gov.ma/data/fr/group/societe), 86206 foreigners lived in Morocco.
According to this data, the place with most foreigners is [Agdal Riyad](http://www.openstreetmap.org/node/2184710850#map=12/33.9738/-6.7641), with 4572 foreigners for 77257 people in total, having almost 6% of foreigners living there. However, foreigners from other Arab countries still counts here.

Also [this source](http://www.huffpostmaghreb.com/2016/03/16/maroc-france-expatries-_n_9476292.html) (I have no idea how reliable it is) says

> Le nombre d'expatriés français au Maroc a augmenté de 4% entre 2014 et 2015 [...]
>
> 51.109. C'est le nombre de Français expatriés recensés au Maroc en 2015

Which translates to:

> Amount of french people living in Morocco increased by 4% between 2014 and 2015
>   [...] 51,109 French people are recorded to live in Morocco in 2015.

Comment: Can a French person become a Moroccan citizen though (other than through marriage)? Because otherwise the UAE will qualify as well as hundreds of thousands of expats live there.

Comment: @JonathanReez The OP aked for granting immigration, not citizenship/nationality. Sure he mentionned political rights which probably requires citizenship/nationality.